# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed

Tags: mac-osx, collectd

I'm trying to use `collectd` on an OSX 10.6 Server (Snow Leopard) building the binaries from scratch works fine and nothing fails, but upon actually trying to run `collectd` I repeatedly recieve this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _plugin_register_config
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/collectd/4.9.1/lib/collectd/syslog.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _plugin_register_config
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/collectd/4.9.1/lib/collectd/syslog.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

This one was installed with a package manager called Homebrew so that is the reason the path prefix is `/usr/local/Cellar/collectd/4.9.1` but I first installed it without any package manager because I thought maybe I had forgotten some dependency, but that wasn't then case so I resorted to using Homebrew with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you also asked this question on Homebrew's website there is an answer from [there](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/issue/820).

Your problem has been [fixed](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/76a9a58e183a5d28ae08c99f7b6b886a5c4cbe54/Library/Formula/collectd.rb) by adding skip_clean? to the Formula.